# Using anonymized student grades in a publication?

Tags: ethics, grades, privacy

Can I use anonymized student grades for a study that could later be published?  The idea would be, for instance, to investigate if a group of students taught by Method A had a different grade distribution than those taught by Method B, and to conclude on the relative merits of both methods.  It wouldn't be feasible go back and obtain consent from the students since a few years have passed.